# How to correctly clear a byte array when reading from Reader.Read()

Tags: go

I'm trying to read bytes from a src using `Reader.Read` but when I print out the data I'm noticing random characters interspersed throughout the output at the beginning of lines which makes me think I'm not clearing the buffer correctly but I'm not sure how to do it being new to Go.

```golang
numRead := 1
for numRead > 0 {
    p := make([]byte, 100)
    numRead, _ = hijack.Reader.Read(p) //hijack is a struct that points to a reader
    p = p[:numRead]
    fmt.Printf("%s", p)
}
```

Some lines come out okay like

> Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/plugin-support/1.0-alpha-1/plugin-support-1.0-alpha-1.pom (5 KB at 25.1 KB/sec)

Others will have a character at the beginning like this

> hDownloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom (5 KB at 27.4 KB/sec)

Comment: There's nothing to clear, you're making a new slice for every read. Are you sure your Read method returns whole lines? (It shouldn't, but you seem to assume that here)

Comment: @JimB well according to the doc I'm just reading 100 bytes everytime and relying on the newlines that I read from the Reader to advance me to the next line

Comment: Ok, it sounded like you were expecting this to print line by line. What is the Reader doing? Are there any non-ascii characters in the output, which might be getting split?

Comment: @ymonad sure, here's the doc for it https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/api/types#HijackedResponse

Comment: @JimB Reader is reading the stdout from a docker exec command that  is building a maven project

Comment: Start by using a better pattern to read -- there's no reason to allocate a new slice every time, or use such a small buffer, and you're not checking your error value. For example: https://play.golang.org/p/e-_lYb9lo2. Are the stdout and stderr combined, and possible showing interleaved output?